# how to start Teamviewer on boot

Tags: boot, autostart, teamviewer

I need to start TeamViewer on boot. I tried to add the command to `/usr/bin/teamviewer --daemon start` to the startup applications as ypu can see below:

[image: Startup list]

[image: command]

But it won't start. Any suggestions?

Comment: Enter the command `/usr/bin/teamviewer --daemon start` in a terminal and check if that actually starts the software

Comment: It already does autostart because of the systemd unit. Teamviewer is also unkillable as it will autostart itself after being killed.

Comment: Please remove that line and investigate the problem more deeply.  Teamviewer when installed will by itself do a `sudo systemctl enable teamviewerd.service`  and start the server. You probably have an error somewhere. Could be as simple as wrong credentials.  start with `teamviewer status` :) Please alter the question with new info.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `crontab`. You just need to..

- Enter a terminal and type `crontab -e`
- If you are asked to do so, follow the instructions on the prompt to select an editor. It will display a list of available editors. select the one you want.
- When the editor opens, you will see a config file. At the bottom of the file, add the following:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/teamviewer --daemon start
```

- Be sure to save, and you are done. Make sure you enter the full path to any commands you enter. For example, if you were calling `echo`, instead of `echo` you would need to use `/usr/bin/echo`.

To see everything cron can do, check out the manual page with `man crontab`.

Comment: I tried this, but it results in a start-up crash "Ubuntu 20.04 has encountered an internal error"

Comment: @Deffo Then it is probably the command...  What is the error?  You have to use `sudo` to start teamviewer in server mode. [See here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rjrgw71zoI4)

Comment: This is not needed. When working teamviewer starts itself and will also restart itself when you kill the deamon it runs under. The only way to not have it start is by disabling the systemd unit. In ALL other situations teamviewer forces itself to be active.

Comment: @Rinzwind No wonder it was giving internal errors. I should have suspected that it would likely be loaded by systemd. Im having a hindsight 20/20 moment. Thanks. Do you mind if I edit my answer, or would you rather answer yourself?

Comment: @Deffo See above comments. Try  `/usr/bin/teamviewer --daemon enable`.

Comment: @NateT go for it ;)